# List index out of bound

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a single unique element in the list.
There are n similar numbers in the list.

The list index out of bound appears when i'm trying to run a while loop.
There is a single unique element in the list.

> while (arr[0]==arr[1]):
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

```
n=int(input())
arr=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
arr.sort()
while (arr[0]==arr[1]):
    for i in range(n):
        arr.pop(0)
print(arr[0])
```

Input
The first line consists of an integer n, is the size of each group.
The second line contains the unordered elements of the room number list.

5

1 2 3 6 5 4 4 2 5 3 6 1 6 5 3 2 4 1 2 5 1 4 3 6 8 4 3 1 5 6 2

output

8

Comment: if n is big enough, after a while your list is empty...

Comment: There is a single unique value in the list

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, please share the exact input you entered before getting this error.

Comment: @Kevin added that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the unique element in your list is at the end of the list, after your `while` loop iterates enough times, it will have removed all duplicates, and the list will have a length of one.

At this point, `arr[0] == arr[1]` will crash, because `arr[1]` references the second element of your list, but your list does not have two elements.

You could change your while loop's conditional so that it also ends when the length reaches one:

```
while (len(arr) > 1 and arr[0]==arr[1]):
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>test.py
5
1 2 3 6 5 4 4 2 5 3 6 1 6 5 3 2 4 1 2 5 1 4 3 6 8 4 3 1 5 6 2
8
```

Comment: Thank you for this insight, really helped me!